# Check dynamic page if changed on php via curl or other way

Tags: php, bash, curl, etag

i have a question for checking : "is page content changed?". etag is very good solution but i want to checking any url if developer of web page used etag or not. and i dont want to download full page before if it is not changed. it is possible static file with `last-modified` meta via curl but it is not possible on dynamic page if developer didn't use etag or any method.

i dont want to use `md5(file_get_content("http://.."))` or same way.

solution must like `curl --head http://.... | grep ..| awk ..`

sorry for language,
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using HTTP, the `last-modified` header is the only chance to check that a file or a dynamic page has been updated without downloading the whole resource. If the developer don't cares about that header then there is no chance

Comment: i understand , thanks. well , do you think this method that `md5(file_get_content("http://.."))` is bad ?

Comment: ok :) thanks a lot. I wanted to like other way, but I have no choice.

Comment: If you can control the remote end, you could set the `last-modified` header dynamically by PHP but as I said only if you can control the remote end

Comment: thanks , i understand that. but i want to checking any url on web. :)

Comment: Then there is no chance except of the downloading and checking using `md5`.. Hopefully the global internet speed will not go down after you started your test... :)

Comment: :) no, this will be  test script. internet is in safe :)

Answer (score 2):

Agree and MD5 is probably the best option, but you can improve on your method, no need for file_get_content just use:

```
md5_file("http://..")
```

(see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php)